# SXA Custom index not used by Search Results component

Tags: sxa, azure-search, index

Following the SXA documentation [Configure SXA indexing](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/configure-sxa-indexing.html), I have created my custom indexes :

[image]

Then I have created a patch config file for the corresponding index definitions.

On a page I use a Search Result component, and when I check the Sitecore logs, I can see the used index is "sitecore_sxa_master_index" instead of my custom index.

On preview mode (master db) :

```
2019-03-15T10:17:20  PID[11424] Information 21412 10:17:20 INFO  AzureSearch Query [sitecore_sxa_master_index]: &search=(language_1:(fr\-FR) AND template_1:(ca5cfa2adb5641d9aa3adab73b86d677))&$filter=(latestversion_1 and (((path_1/any(t:t eq '0d95c065a3e24304a308c186c12b553e')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '93c838194064443787a2839f10c1c0fb')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '92e68bef47ff4a29bc87b26b62dbe4c4')) and searchable)) and (path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')))&queryType=full&$count=true

2019-03-15T10:17:20  PID[11424] Information 21412 10:17:20 INFO  AzureSearch Query [sitecore_sxa_master_index]: &search=(language_1:(fr\-FR) AND template_1:(ca5cfa2adb5641d9aa3adab73b86d677))&$filter=(latestversion_1 and (((path_1/any(t:t eq '0d95c065a3e24304a308c186c12b553e')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '93c838194064443787a2839f10c1c0fb')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '92e68bef47ff4a29bc87b26b62dbe4c4')) and searchable)) and (path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')))&queryType=full&$skip=0&$top=50&$count=true
```

On front end (web db) :

```
2019-03-15T10:18:19  PID[11424] Information 13716 10:18:19 INFO  AzureSearch Query [sitecore_sxa_web_index]: &search=(language_1:(fr\-FR) AND template_1:(ca5cfa2adb5641d9aa3adab73b86d677))&$filter=(latestversion_1 and (((path_1/any(t:t eq '0d95c065a3e24304a308c186c12b553e')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '93c838194064443787a2839f10c1c0fb')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '92e68bef47ff4a29bc87b26b62dbe4c4')) and searchable)) and (path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')))&queryType=full&$count=true

2019-03-15T10:18:19  PID[11424] Information 13716 10:18:19 INFO  AzureSearch Query [sitecore_sxa_web_index]: &search=(language_1:(fr\-FR) AND template_1:(ca5cfa2adb5641d9aa3adab73b86d677))&$filter=(latestversion_1 and (((path_1/any(t:t eq '0d95c065a3e24304a308c186c12b553e')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '93c838194064443787a2839f10c1c0fb')) and searchable) or ((path_1/any(t:t eq '92e68bef47ff4a29bc87b26b62dbe4c4')) and searchable)) and (path_1/any(t:t eq '76b6d453423a497db0d427779f866fd7')))&queryType=full&$skip=0&$top=50&$orderby=name___s desc&$count=true
```

What is wrong with my configuration / understanding ?

Comment: Can you check via ShowConfig.aspx that your custom indexes are defined there?

Comment: Could be related (not sure just something I came across) https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.255689/releases